# Using a growth formula for grouped observations

Tags: macros, statistics, stata, stata-macros

I have a dataset which is shown below:

```
clear

input year price growth id
2008 5  -0.444  1
2009 .  .       1
2010 7  -0.222  1   
2011 9   0      1
2011 8  -0.111  1
2012 9   0      1
2013 11  0.22   1 
2012 10  0      2      
2013 12  0.2    2
2013 .  .       2  
2014 13  0.3    2    
2015 17  0.7    2
2015 16  0.6    2    
end
```

I want to generate variable `growth` which is the growth of `price`. The growth formula is:

```
growth = price of second-year - price of base year / price of base year
```

The base year is always `2012`.

How can I generate this `growth` variable for each group of observation (by `id`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base price can be picked out directly by `egen`:

```
bysort id: egen price_b = total(price * (year == 2012))
generate wanted = (price - price_b) / price_b
```

Notice that `total` is used along with the assumption that, for each `id`, you have only one observation with `year = 2012`.

Comment: See https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055 for a review of this and related devices.

Comment: I had forgotten about `egen`'s `total()` function! Equivalently, one could do: `bysort id: egen obs = total(_n * (year == 2012))` and `bysort id: generate wanted = (price - price[obs]) / price[obs]`.

Comment: @PearlySpencer The help for `egen` specifically advises against using subscripts `_n` in calls. The key is that `egen` functions may change the sort order of the data temporarily. It will be safe whenever that doesn't happen but it is not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
bysort id: generate obs = _n
generate double wanted = .

levelsof id, local(ids)

foreach x of local ids {
    summarize obs if id == `x' & year == 2012, meanonly 
    bysort id: replace wanted = (price - price[`=obs[r(min)]']) /    ///
                                 price[`=obs[r(min)]'] if id == `x'
}
```

If the `id` values are consecutive, then the following will be faster:

```
forvalues i = 1 / 2 {
    summarize obs if id == `i' & year == 2012, meanonly 
    bysort id: replace wanted = (price - price[`=obs[r(min)]']) /    ///
                                 price[`=obs[r(min)]'] if id == `i'
}
```

Results:

```
list, sepby(id)

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     | year   price   growth   id   obs       wanted |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. | 2008       5    -.444    1     1   -.44444444 |
  2. | 2009       .        .    1     2            . |
  3. | 2010       7    -.222    1     3   -.22222222 |
  4. | 2011       9        0    1     4            0 |
  5. | 2011       8    -.111    1     5   -.11111111 |
  6. | 2012       9        0    1     6            0 |
  7. | 2013      11      .22    1     7    .22222222 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  8. | 2012      10        0    2     1            0 |
  9. | 2013      12       .2    2     2           .2 |
 10. | 2013       .        .    2     3            . |
 11. | 2014      13       .3    2     4           .3 |
 12. | 2015      17       .7    2     5           .7 |
 13. | 2015      16       .6    2     6           .6 |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```